# Certificate error message whenever I use wget

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, wget

Whenever I use wget for the below or typically anything,

```
sudo wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

I receive an error stating:

```
--2020-04-24 20:41:33--  https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64
Resolving www.dropbox.com (www.dropbox.com)... 162.125.6.1, 2620:100:601c:1::a27d:601
Connecting to www.dropbox.com (www.dropbox.com)|162.125.6.1|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.dropbox.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.dropbox.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

This is causing broader connection problems, but this is the most common and immediate one that I cannot seem to find much support on. Using Ubuntu 20.04 and literally just did a re-image of my computer 3 hours ago (probably has something to do with this...)

EDIT Additional Information from running wget -d cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.17.2.tar.xz:

```
wget -d cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.17.2.tar.xz
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.20.3 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/negfrequency/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Converted file name 'linux-4.17.2.tar.xz' (UTF-8) -> 'linux-4.17.2.tar.xz' (UTF-8)
--2020-04-24 20:33:17--  http://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.17.2.tar.xz
Resolving cdn.kernel.org (cdn.kernel.org)... 151.101.201.176, 2a04:4e42:50::432
Caching cdn.kernel.org => 151.101.201.176 2a04:4e42:50::432
Connecting to cdn.kernel.org (cdn.kernel.org)|151.101.201.176|:80... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x00005588dc6a7f10 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET /pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.17.2.tar.xz HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: cdn.kernel.org
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/x-xz
Last-Modified: Sat, 16 Jun 2018 07:34:25 GMT
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 4
Content-Length: 102167060
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 00:33:22 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-dca17760-DCA
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1587774798.899562,VS0,VE4554

---response end---
200 OK
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
Length: 102167060 (97M) [application/x-xz]
Saving to: ‘linux-4.17.2.tar.xz’

linux-4.17.2.tar.xz 100%[===================>]  97.43M  6.87MB/s    in 15s     

2020-04-24 20:33:37 (6.35 MB/s) - ‘linux-4.17.2.tar.xz’ saved [102167060/102167060]
```

EDIT:

Additional information /usr/bin/wget is the path:

```
ii ca-certificates 20190110ubuntu1 all Common CA certificates
ii wget 1.20.3-1ubuntu1 amd64 retrieves files from the web
```

Answer (score 1):

This error would pop up when the website you re trying to talk to does not have a valid SSL certificate. And if that is the case, you would not be able to resolve THEIR issue with THEIR ssl, unless you own that remote website.

Thus the Suggestion from `wget`: to use `--no-check-certificate` parameter, so wget will not try to validate the SSL when connecting.

If your error is: `Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority`, then you should make sure that your server/computer TIME is correct.

Comment: I dont think this is the case, since the site im accessing is dropbox.com, and it also occurs with any other site i ping with wget.

Comment: wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.17.2.tar.xz resulted in the same error

Comment: Hm, I am on Ubuntu 20.04 atm, and doing `wget https://dropbox.com` does not throw any such errors, so I cannot replicate it. could you provide the full path of wget on your system (using: `which wget`), and the output of `dpkg -l|egrep "wget|ca-cert"` ?

Comment: This matches my versions, so, could you add Under YOUR question: the complete output of: `wget -d cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.17.2.tar.xz`? as this could be a DNS issue from your network

Comment: So it all looks ok, where is the error for `--no-check-certificate` ? Could you provide the same output also for dropbox.com ? just the main domain, not your exact files there, but use the same hostname in front.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212456/discussion-between-will-kinsman-and-ron).

Comment: Is you computer's Clock correct? try to update it,and then try wget, this is a common issue when SSL is not locally validated. I also wrote in the chat..

Comment: Clock was correct, reimaged my computer a second time to resolve the issue.